# How to get post category list as select in front-end?

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, widgets, ajax

I use widget plugin Getting the random post & URL via ajax. 
I want to add function, that allows users on frontend choose category, and than display random posts from this category.

```
function get_random_post_tu() {

    // Simple as that, get a random post
    $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=1');

    /**
     * This actually gives us an array of post objects, so we should double check 
     * if there is indeed a post in there.
     */
    if (is_array($posts) && isset($posts[0])) {

        $data = array();
        $data['link'] = get_permalink($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['title'] = get_the_title($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['thumb'] = get_the_post_thumbnail($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['content'] = get_post_field('post_content', $posts[0]->ID);

        /**
         *  Making a structure like this will make your work in the javascript
         *  a lot easier when you want to get the title and link from the respons
         *  data.
         *  The JSON format is always good for passing structured data (like objects
         *  or arrays) to a javascript function.                     
         */             
        print_r(json_encode($data));

    } else {
        // If there is nothing in there, print a 0
        print 0;
    }    

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result

}
```

It is a function php, that displays post.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.grp_getnew').on('click', function(){
        var data = {
            action: 'get_random_post_tu'
        };

        $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            if (response!=0) {
                var $link = $("<a href='" + response.link + "'>" + response.title + "</a><span >" + response.content +"</span>");
                $('.grp_content').html($link);
            }
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

it's function js. 
As i understand, i must call category list via `wp_get_post_categories`and than i don't know, how to link category to randomizer. I need help! Help me please!

Comment: @Fischi  and if it is custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can extend your AJAX function. I assume you already registered it correctly.

instead of encoding your array by yourself, you can use the WordPress function `wp_send_json()`, which also includes a `die()`.

I would recommend making a status variable for "no posts" or other errors as well.

The query is changed in the `$args`, if the category ID is set.

```
function get_random_post_tu() {

    // Simple as that, get a random post
    // I put it in an array to make it easier to read
    $args = array(
        'orderby'     => 'rand',
        'numberposts' => 1
    );

    // Add the Category parameter, if set
    if ( isset( $_POST['usecategory'] ) && intval( $_POST['usecategory'] ) != 0 ) {
        $args['category'] = $_POST['usecategory'];
    }
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    /**
     * This actually gives us an array of post objects, so we should double check 
     * if there is indeed a post in there.
     */
    $data = array();
    if (is_array($posts) && isset($posts[0])) {

        // add this to use on frontend
        $data['status']  = 'success';
        $data['link']    = get_permalink($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['title']   = get_the_title($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['thumb']   = get_the_post_thumbnail($posts[0]->ID);
        $data['content'] = get_post_field('post_content', $posts[0]->ID);

    } else {

        // add a error status
        $data['status'] = 'error';

    }    

    // use the WordPress built in function
    wp_send_json( $data ); // this is required to return a proper result

}
```

In the frontend you need to pass the value of the dropdown (in this case `#usecategory`) to the AJAX request. I already built in the error handling that we created in the function before.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.grp_getnew').on('click', function(){
        var data = {
            action: 'get_random_post_tu',
            usecategory: $('#categoryselect').val()
        };

        $.post( ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            if ( response.status != 'error' ) {
                var $link = $("<a href='" + response.link + "'>" + response.title + "</a><span >" + response.content +"</span>");
                $('.grp_content').html($link);
            }
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

So, all you need to do now is create a category dropdown and a button to fire the request.

In the template:

```
// Use the [Codex][1] to define the correct $args for you
<?php
    $args = array(
        'id' => 'categoryselect'
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>
<button class="grp_getnew">Let's go!</button>
```

That should be all you need :)

Comment: Ohohohohohohooh! Thanks! So nice! all i have modified is in js instead ajax_url i return ajax_object.ajax_url. Thats all! 100+ to your karma!

Comment: fischi, And if it's custom post type?

Comment: And if it's custom post type?

Comment: If it is a custom post type, you just need to add `'post_type' =>'yourcustomposttype'` to your arguments list :)

Comment: and wp_dropdown_categories( $args ) ?

Comment: I tryed but does't work=(

Comment: See the next question ;)